# MySQL query GROUP works in console, does not work in PHP script

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a function with this mysqli query but for some reason it does not print the desired result in php script.
What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT id
FROM personal WHERE structure = ?
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id FROM presence WHERE service = 'shift1' AND year = ? AND month = ? AND day = ? ) 
AND id IN 
(SELECT id FROM qualification WHERE idqualification = '1' or idqualification = '2')
ORDER BY RAND()
) t
GROUP BY t.id
```

update: this is my function. It should find persons working in a day having those qualifications and count them

```
function presence_by_qualification($structure, $day, $month, $year)
{
global $connection;
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT id
FROM personal WHERE structure = ?
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id FROM presence WHERE service = 'shift1' AND year = ? AND month = ? AND day = ? ) 
AND id IN 
(SELECT id FROM qualification WHERE idqualification = '1' or idqualification = '2')
ORDER BY RAND()
) t
GROUP BY t.id");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $structure, $day, $month, $year);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($counts);
results = $stmt -> fetch();
return $results;
}
```

I store the result in an array so I can count them.

```
$presencebyqualif[] = presence_by_qualification($structure, $day, $month, $year);
```

I am using it like this:

```
$structure = "1029";
$day = "01";
$month = "05";
$year = "2019";
```

They are all variables. It should show the counted number of people on shift having these specific qualifications.

Comment: Can you post your PHP script?

Comment: PHP doesn't manipulate your query in anyway, if it works directly on the server it should work on web, please post your php code

Comment: I posted the function

Comment: Please post your requirement, too. So we can identify that what wrong with your SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed wrong order of params in bind_param() function. You should add params value in order of "?" you used in your query. Please do following changes:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $structure, $year, $month, $day);
```

Hope it may helpful to you!!